# Loading Highcharts via shim using RequireJS and maintaining jQuery dependency

Tags: javascript, highcharts, requirejs, js-amd

I'm attempting to load the Highcharts library using a shim in RequireJS.  However, when Highcharts loads, it throws an exception because it can't access the jQuery methods it depends on.

The require config looks like so:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",

    shim: {

        'libs/highcharts/highcharts.src.js': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: function(jQuery)
            {
                this.HighchartsAdapter = jQuery;

                return this.Highcharts;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The exception that is thrown is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

and is in regards to this line:

```
dataLabels: merge(defaultLabelOptions, {
```

The issue is the `merge` call, which eventually maps itself back to jQuery (or some other adapter that Highcharts supports; but I'm just using jQuery).

I'm not sure exactly how to make sure Highcharts gets access to jQuery using RequireJS and shim.

Has anyone used RequireJS and Highcharts together before?  I guess the issue isn't specific to highcharts, but any library that has other sorts of dependencies.

Thanks in advance for any advice or points to the correct direction!

**To add further context,  in hopes that someone who is familiar with require.js or shims will be able to help without having to be too intimately familiar with highcharts, here's some source that sets up this `merge` method in Highcharts**

```
var globalAdapter = win.HighchartsAdapter,
adapter = globalAdapter || {},

// Utility functions. If the HighchartsAdapter is not defined, 
// adapter is an empty object
// and all the utility functions will be null. In that case they are 
// populated by the
// default adapters below.

// {snipped code}

merge = adapter.merge

// {snipped code}

if (!globalAdapter && win.jQuery) {
    var jQ = win.jQuery;

    // {snipped code}

    merge = function () {
        var args = arguments;
        return jQ.extend(true, null, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    };

    // {snipped code}
}
```

The `win` object is a reference set up to `window` at the beginning of the script.  So, I thought adding `window.jQuery = jQuery;` to the export method on the shim would result in highcharts picking up the jQuery reference; but it didn't.

Again, any insight, info, advice, or heckles would be appreciated at this point - I'm at a complete loss, and starting to question whether trying to implement and AMD package system in browser javascript is even worth it.

---

After accepting the answer from *pabera* below I thought it appropriate to update my question to reflect how his answer helped my solution (though, it's basically his answer).

RequireJS uses "paths" to find libs that aren't "AMD" supported and loads them on your page.  the "shim" object allows you to define dependencies for the libraries defined in paths.  The dependencies must be loaded before requirejs will try to load the dependent script.

The exports property provides a mechanism to tell requirejs how to determine if the library is loaded.  For core libs like jquery, backbone, socketio, etc they all export some window level variable (`Backbone`, `io`, `jQuery` and `$`, etc).  You simply provide that variable name as the `exports` property, and requirejs will be able to determine when the lib is loaded.

Once your definitions are done, you can use `requirejs`' `define` function as expected.

Here's my example `require.config` object:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/js/",

    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery',
        socketio: 'http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io', //for loading the socket.io client library
        highcharts: 'libs/highcharts/highcharts.src',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone'
    },

    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },

        socketio: {
            exports: 'io'
        },

        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },

        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },

        highcharts: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'Highcharts'
        }
    }
});
```

As *pabera* mentioned before, this is for `Require.JS` version `2.0.1`.

I hope someone gets some use out of this; I know it road blocked me for a little while; so hopefully we kept you from banging your head into the same spot in the wall that we did, by posting this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and I was struggling around many hours until I saw your entry here. Then I started over from scratch and now it works for me at least.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl:'/js/',
    paths:{
      jquery:'vendor/jquery',
      handlebars: 'vendor/handlebars',
      text: 'vendor/require-text',
      chaplin:'vendor/chaplin',
      underscore:'vendor/underscore',
      backbone:'vendor/backbone',
      highcharts: 'vendor/highcharts'
    },

    shim: {
      backbone: {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
      },
      underscore: {
        exports: '_'
      },    
      highcharts: {
        exports: 'Highcharts'
      }    
    },
});
```

Since I use [Chaplin](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin) on top of Backbone, I am including some more files in my paths attribute. Highcharts has a similar structure to Backbone so I thought I could load it the same way. It works for me now. As you can see, I am introducing highcharts in the paths attribute already to export it as a shim afterwords.

Maybe this helps, otherwise let's try to contribute on it even more to solve your problem.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see what I come up with; thanks for the response!

Comment: I use `require.js 2.0.1`, just in case it is important. Good luck

Comment: I changed to use the normal require.js (instead of w/jquery) and used the jquery shim, with your explanation/example of paths/shims.  after reading the documentation some more, now i understand what's going on - thanks a ton!

Comment: Why not make your baseUrl '/js/vendor/'?

Answer (score 2):

Although jQuery can be used as an AMD module it will still export itself to the window anyway so any scripts depending on the global `jQuery` or `$` will still work as long as jQuery has loaded first.

Have you tried setting a path? jQuery is an interesting one because although you're encoruaged not to name your modules by the RequireJS documentation, jQuery actually does.

**From the jQuery source**

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
}
```

What that means is you will need to tell RequireJS where to find 'jquery'. So:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'path/to/jquery'
    }
});
```

If you're interested in why jQuery registers itself this way then [there is a pretty large comment in the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/exports/amd.js) which goes into more detail

Comment: I actually downloaded the require.js w/jquery code [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#get) thinking that it'd at least be the "suggested way to load jquery with require.js" so that's what I'm using.  As I understand, jQuery is pretty much handled by the require.js source by using that download which is supposed to (i guess) negate the need for using 'paths' to set the path for jquery, or shimming jquery.