# require js shim not working for this code

Tags: requirejs

I have the following code.

```
<script src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
<script>
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl:'js/modules/',
        paths:{
            'bbn':'../libs/backbone',
            'underscore':'../libs/underscore'
        },
        shim:{
            'bbn':{
                exports:'B',
                deps:['underscore']
            }
        }
    })  
    requirejs(['bbn'], function(B){
        console.log(B)
    });
</script>
```

The function parameter `B` is not pointing to `Backbone`. Instead its getting logged as `undefined`.

I followed the following post and arrived to this point:

[Loading Highcharts via shim using RequireJS and maintaining jQuery dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907519/loading-highcharts-via-shim-using-requirejs-and-maintaining-jquery-dependency)

I see both `underscore` and `backbone` JavaScript files getting downloaded in firebug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Underscore is not AMD compat either, so make sure you `shim` that too:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl:'js/modules/',
paths:{
    'bbn':'../libs/backbone',
    'underscore':'../libs/underscore'
},
shim:{
    'bbn':{
        exports:'Backbone',
        deps:['underscore']
    },
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    }
}
})  
requirejs(['bbn'], function(Backbone){
console.log(Backbone)
});
```

You will see Underscore being downloaded but because it not defined as a proper module RequireJS just treats it as a normal JS file and doesn't get a return value

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Underscore (~1.6.0 as of writing this) is AMD-compatible. Do not use it as a shim or you may run into issues.