# Highchart/Highstock AMD support

Tags: highcharts, amd

Could anyone confirm if current versions of Highchart/Highstock support AMD - i.e. can I simply point the locations of the scripts using require.js or what should I use instead (shims or paths or..)?

I'm getting random loading errors mainly during "cold" start. There're two different errors:

1. **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (line 288, col 506)**
2. no errors in the console but the actual chart doesn't get displayed only its bottom part "navigator".

I'm using google chrome with caching disabled. If I press F5 5-10 times likely one of reloads will produce the error.

I've tried the following three options (I'm using highstock herein HC):

1. HS configured via "script"
2. HS configured via "shim"
3. HS configured as a generic AMD

still getting the error.

Comment: Have you tried it? Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: PLease take look at related topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907519/loading-highcharts-via-shim-using-requirejs-and-maintaining-jquery-dependency

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan, thanks - looks like a tricky one, also in my case it works in FF but fails in Chrome, which I've recently found out just to add some fun:(